# Integral of Hodge Star of Differential Form over Submanifold of Complementary Dimension which Intersects Transversely

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, hodge-theory

Let $([M]^n, g)$ be a closed, smooth, oriented, Riemannian manifold, and let $[S]^k$ and $[T]^{n-k}$ be closed, smooth, oriented submanifolds of $M$ which intersect transversely. Let $\omega$ be a differential $k$-form on $M$ with $\displaystyle \oint\limits_{[S]} \omega = r \ne 0$. Let $\eta$ be the Hodge star of $\omega$.

What can be said about $\displaystyle \oint\limits_{[T]} \eta$? Would it help if the $\mathbb{Z}\pi$-intersection number of $S$ and $T$ were $\pm 1$ (where $\pi = \pi_1(M)$)?

Comment: Did you try some simple example? Say two standard copies of $\mathbb S^1$'s in $M = \mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1$.

Comment: Definitely, if $M = S \times T$, $\displaystyle \oint\limits_{[T]} \eta = \frac{ \langle \omega, \omega \rangle\text{Vol}(M)}{r}$

Comment: I would conjecture $\displaystyle \oint\limits_{[T]} \eta = \frac{|\text{int}([S],[T])\langle \omega, \omega \rangle\text{Vol}(M)}{r}$, where $\text{int}([S],[T])$ is the integral intersection number of $[S]$ and $[T]$ in [M].

Comment: (My first comment should be true up to sign.)

Comment: You should be thinking about closed forms and Poincaré duality, I suspect.

Comment: $[S]$ and $[T]$ are mostly disjoint (as far as integration is concerned), and since we're free to modify differential forms locally (e.g. using bump functions), knowing how $\omega$ behaves on $[S]$ tells us essentially nothing about how $\eta$ behaves on $[T]$. As Ted Shifrin points out, if $\omega$ is subject to some global constraint like closure then there may be something interesting to say.

Comment: Also, the expression relating $\int_S\omega$ and $\int_T\eta$ for $M=S\times T$ doesn't seem to be true; in nontrivial cases like $M=S^1\times S^1$ you can make the two integrals (as well as $\langle\omega,\omega\rangle$) whatever you want independently of each other with appropriate choice of $\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer, in the case $M = S \times T$, let $[S]$ and $[T]$ be $S$ and $T$ with orientations, let $[M]$ be $M$ with its induced orientation from $[S]$ and $[T]$, and let $\zeta_0$ be the volume form on $[M]$. Then every $n$-form on $M$ may be written $f\xi_0$ for some function $f: M \to \mathbb{R} \in \Lambda^0(M)$. Similarly, let $\omega_0$ and $\eta_0$ be the volume forms on $[S]$ and $[T]$ respectively. Then 1) $\omega_0 \wedge \eta_0 = \zeta_0$, 2) $\displaystyle\text{Vol}(M) = \oint\limits_{[M]} \zeta_0 = \oint\limits_{[S] \times [T]} \omega_0 \wedge \eta_0 = \left(\oint\limits_{[[S]]} \omega_0\right)\left(\oint\limits_{[T]} \eta_0\right) = \text{Vol}(S)\text{Vol}(T)$, and 3) for any forms $\omega \in \Lambda^k(S)$ and $\eta \in \Lambda^{n-k}(T)$, we have functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ with $\omega = g_1\omega_0$ and $\eta = g_2\eta_0$. Hence, $\displaystyle \oint\limits_{[S]} \omega = \oint\limits_{[S]} g_1\omega_0 = \pm\left(\int\limits_S g_1\right)\text{Vol}(S)$.

Suppose $\displaystyle \oint\limits_{[S]} \omega = r \ne 0$

Now, ${}^*\omega$ has $\omega \wedge {}^*\omega = \langle\omega,\omega\rangle\zeta_0 = \langle\omega,\omega\rangle(\omega_0 \wedge \eta_0) = g_1^2(\omega_0 \wedge \eta_0)$, so ${}^*\omega = g_1\eta_0$. Hence, $\displaystyle \oint\limits_{[T]} {}^*\omega = \oint\limits_{[T]} g_1\eta_0 = \pm\left(\int\limits_T g_1\right)\text{Vol}(T) = \pm\frac{\left(\int\limits_T g_1\right)\left(\int\limits_S g_1\right)\text{Vol}(S)\text{Vol}(T)}{\left(\int\limits_S g_1\right)\text{Vol}(S)} = \pm\frac{\left(\int\limits_T g_1\right)\left(\int\limits_S g_1\right)\left(\oint\limits_{[S]} \omega_0\right)\left(\oint\limits_{[T]} \eta_0\right)}{\left(\int\limits_S g_1\right)\text{Vol}(S)} = \pm\frac{\left(\int\limits_{S \times T} g_1^2\right)\left(\oint\limits_{[S] \times [T]} \omega_0 \wedge \eta_0\right)}{\left(\int\limits_S g_1\right)\text{Vol}(S)} = \pm\frac{\left(\int\limits_{M} g_1^2\right)\left(\oint\limits_{[M]} \zeta_0\right)}{\left(\int\limits_S g_1\right)\text{Vol}(S)} = \pm\frac{\langle\omega,\omega\rangle\text{Vol}(M)}{r}\ \blacksquare$

Comment: Why the brackets everywhere? $M$ is not a homology class. Also, orientations on $S$ and $T$ induce an orientation on their product, not vice-versa.

Comment: I'm borrowing terminology from https://smile.amazon.com/Analysis-Manifolds-Advanced-Books-Classics/dp/0201315963/ : $[M]$ is an orientable manifold together with an orientation. More later

Comment: Your submanifold "$S$" and $"T"$ should really be $S\times \{t\}$ and $\{s\}\times T$ for some $t, s$. So terms like $\int_T g_1$ is quite confusing: it should be $\int_{\{s}\times T\} g_1$. And of course $\int_{S\times \{ t\}} g_1 \int_{\{s\}\times T} g_1  \neq \int_{S\times T} g_1^2$.

Comment: This computation is hard to follow, since it freely conflates forms/functions on $S$, $T$ and $M$ even when the restrictions/extensions are nontrivial, e.g. the expression $\omega_0\wedge\mu_0=\zeta_0$ doesn't make much sense since these forms on only well-defined on different (sub)manifolds. $g_1$ and $\omega$ similarly don't seem to have a consistently defined domain.